# Проблема с переводом в Django 2.1

Tags: django

Я создал форму которая наследуется от AuthenticationForm. Мне нужно было сделать для поля ввода placeholder. Я написал вот так вот:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': _('Username')})
```

Вопрос такой: почему `_('Username')` не переводится как "Имя пользователя". Что вместо `_('Username')` нужно подставить?

К примеру `_('Password')` почему-то переводится.

Функция _() это `from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _`

Надеюсь вы поняли вопрос.

Comment: А у вас вообще есть файл переводов, в котором был бы написан перевод для `Username`?

Comment: `Password` переводится, потому что слово есть во встроенных файлах переводов Django. А `Username` там нет, и написать перевод для него вы должны самостоятельно (как — см. документацию)

Comment: Но тогда почему этот username в label'е переводится по дефолту?

Comment: Потому что оно там с маленькой буквы. А у вас с большой — это разные строки. Для маленькой буквы перевод есть, для большой нету :)

Comment: Или если вы где-то видели с большой буквой — покажите, лично я не нашёл

Comment: Спасибо большое =)

Comment: Я конечно не придераюсь но просто факт - по дефолту перевод с большой буквы ("Имя пользователя"), а когда я username написал с маленькой буквы, то перевод тоже с маленькой ("имя пользователя")

Comment: Кстати где мне файл переводов от django искать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать

```
_('username')
```

вместо

```
_('Username')
```

Comment: Это я понял но дефолтный перевод с большой буквы а когда пишу `_('username')` то переводится с маленькой буквы. Я конечно могу добавить файл переводов, но мне просто интересно почему так?